# How to reproject an image from Polar to Cartesian coordinates in Python?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing

I have an image given in polar coordinates `(phi, r)` with shape `(361, 1001)`.

I want to make a cartesian image with shape `(3000, 3000)` from it to use it on my `QGraphicsScene`.

How can it be done?

P.S. Just now I try to reproject it with OpenCV `linearPolar` function, but cannot set output image size. AFAIK, OpenCV lacks such an option.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

phi_grid = np.linspace(0, np.pi / 3, 361)
r_grid = np.linspace(0, 1, 101)
phi_mesh, r_mesh = np.meshgrid(phi_grid, r_grid, indexing="ij")

amp_mesh = r_mesh + phi_mesh

x_mesh = r_mesh * np.cos(phi_mesh)
y_mesh = r_mesh * np.sin(phi_mesh)

out_pic = cv2.linearPolar(amp_mesh, (0, 180), 101, cv2.WARP_INVERSE_MAP | cv2.WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS)

plt.imshow(out_pic)
plt.show()
```

[image: How can I make it 3000x3000????]

Comment: Can you show us code you have written or options tried already?

Comment: Well, I've just updated the question = )